# Python mockito - Mocking a class which is being instantiated from the testable function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, stubbing

I am bit lost while writing the test case for **UserCompanyRateLimitValidation** class. I am finding difficulty in mocking the class which is being instantiated from inside this class.

```
class UserCompanyRateLimitValidation:
    def __init__(self, user_public_key):
        self.adapter = UserAdapter(user_public_key)
        container = self.adapter.get_user_company_rate_limit()
        super(UserCompanyRateLimitValidation, self).__init__(container,\
                                            UserCompanyRateLimitValidation.TYPE)
```

I have to test this class. I have written test case something like this. I have tried to mock the UserAdapter class but I am not able to do so completely.

```
def test_case_1():
   self.user_public_key = 'TEST_USER_PUBLIC_KEY_XXXXXX1234567890XXXXX'
   UserAdapter_mock = mock(UserAdapter)
   when(UserAdapter_mock).get_user_company_rate_limit().\
                                          thenReturn(get_fake_container_object())

   self.test_obj = UserCompanyRateLimitValidation(self.user_public_key)
```

Here if you see I have mocked get_user_company_rate_limit() call from the testable function, `container = self.adapter.get_user_company_rate_limit()`
 but I am still not able to figure out the way in which I can mock this call,

```
 self.adapter = UserAdapter(user_public_key)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is quite simple if you know the trick.

Creating an object in Python is very much like a function call to the class object. `UserCompanyRateLimitValidation` is 'invoking' `UserAdapter(user_public_key)`. You want to stub the return value of that 'call' to return `UserAdapter_mock`.

You can stub this like you would stub a function in a module. The line you're missing is:

```
when(module_declaring_UserAdapter)\
    .UserAdapter(self.user_public_key)\
    .thenReturn(UserAdapter_mock)
```

After that, calling `module_declaring_UserAdapter.UserAdapter(self.user_public_key)` will return `UserAdapter_mock`.

Here's the link to the section in the manual: https://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/wiki/Stubbing#Modules

You have to be careful to choose the right `module_declaring_UserAdapter`, due to the way the `from ... import ...` statement works. From your code, I'd say you have to pick the module in which `UserCompanyRateLimitValidation` is declared.

Comment: I like this idea...I will test this and let you know...Thanks @Stefan

Comment: Stefan I sincerely apologies for the delay..i will test this asap..Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I tested now and it worked.. Thanks a lot Stefan.. Apologies that you didn't receive the bounty.. I loose them as well...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of looking at it. Say I have this code in which I would like to mock `MyClass`:

```
from some.module import MyClass

class AnotherClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_class = MyClass()
```

One would typically call the imports as shown above. With some slight modification of the import, we can get it into a state where `MyClass` it can be mocked using mockito:

```
from some import module

class AnotherClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_class = module.MyClass()
```

Then the mocking would work like so:

```
from some import module

when(module).MyClass().thenReturn(mock())
```